# How to get reproducible weights initializaiton in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reproducible-research

1. I set both numpy and tensorflow random seeds as [suggested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408950/reproducible-numbers-in-keras-tensorflow)
2. Generate some data - this part  is reproducible, gives same results always
3. Create a simple network and make a prediction (without training, just with random weights) - **prediction is different every time**

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, optimizers
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(32)
tf.set_random_seed(33)

random_data = np.random.rand(10, 2048)
print(random_data[:,0])

def make_classifier():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_dim=2048))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-4),
              loss='binary_crossentropy')
    return model
model = make_classifier()
# model.summary()
model.predict(random_data)
```

When I re-run the whole cell, the print statement always outputs `[0.85888927 0.23846818 0.17757634 0.07244977 0.71119893 0.09223853 0.86074647 0.31838194 0.7568638  0.38197083]`. However the prediction is different every time:

```
array([[0.5825965 ],
       [0.8677979 ],
       [0.70151913],
       [0.64572096],
       [0.78101623],
       [0.76483005],
       [0.7946336 ],
       [0.6281612 ],
       [0.8208673 ],
       [0.8273002 ]], dtype=float32)
```

```
array([[0.51012236],
       [0.6562015 ],
       [0.5593666 ],
       [0.686155  ],
       [0.6488372 ],
       [0.5966359 ],
       [0.6236731 ],
       [0.58099884],
       [0.68447435],
       [0.58886844]], dtype=float32)
```

And so on.

1. How do I get reproducible prediction for a just-initialized network?
2. When does the weights initialization happen exactly? when I compile the model or?..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get reproducible results in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419510/how-to-get-reproducible-results-in-keras)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.keras.initializers` objects have a `seed` argument for reproducible initialization.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42)

for _ in range(10):
    print(np.round(initializer((4,)), 3))
```

```
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
[-0.377 -0.003  0.373 -0.831]
```

In a Keras layer, you can use it like this:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, 
                      activation='relu', 
                      input_dim=2048,
                      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42))
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped, although I had to write it like glorot_uniform:
```Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_dim=2048, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=42))```

Comment: I'm using a neural network of the form `model = Sequential(); model.add(LSTM(nodes, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=1))); ...` but at every execution I was getting different results. Somewhere else I read about `tf.random.set_seed(0)`, so I added it before the second line and now it is working correctly, i.e. at each execution the list `model_history.history['loss']` contains always the same values.

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling a lot with this and turns out there are quite a few points that have to be set in order to achieve complete consistency for every case:

First of all, make sure the data (and the order of the data) that you feed to your model is consistent. Then, for the model weights initialization:

1)numpy random seed

```
import numpy as np
np.seed(1)
```

2)tensor flow random seed

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(2)
```

3)python random seed

```
import random
random.seed(3)
```

Additionally to that, you have to set two (if you have multiprocessing capabilities) arguments to `model.fit`. These ones are not often mentioned on the answers I've seen around:

```
model.fit(..., shuffle=False, use_multiprocessing=False)
```

Only then I have achieved complete consistency in training runs.

Hope that helps people!

Answer (score 1):

I think a better practice is

```py
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(
    seed
)
```

ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with that too. The version of Tensorflow and Keras is 2.14.0.

What worked for me was:

```
seed = 0
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
```

I hope this helps!